# Show the text form a TextInput in class A in a Label in class B

Tags: label, kivy-language, textinput

I'm so deeply stuck in this!!! I tried through hours of frustration to get this little thing done... Every help would be so kind and relieving.
So here's my problem:

I know there's a bit of code, but **the hole question turns just about two classes**...

In the class Datum, I want a Label.

In the class Alledaten, I want a TextInput.

Now I want that TextInput to bind on_text_validate to update my Labels text.

**I know how that works within the same class... (its pretty simple)
but not in two different classes**

'''

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    from kivy.metrics import dp, sp
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    
    from wochenplaner_script import CodefuerWochenplaner_ausgeglichen as CW
    
    Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, .5, .5)
    
    # 1. File Managing -------------------------------
    class Wochenplan(App):
        def build(self):
            # Designate .kv design file
            # Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
            sm = ScreenManager()
            sm.add_widget(Maininterface(name="screen_maininterface"))
            sm.current = "screen_maininterface"
            return sm
    
    
    class Screenmanager(ScreenManager):
        pass
    
    
    # 2. Code ----------------------------------------
    class Zeitplanprotag(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Zeitplanprotag, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
            y = Window.system_size[1]
    
            for i in range(1, 16, 1):
                buttonleft = Button(text=f'{i} left', size_hint=(.5, None), height=y * 0.1, halign="left", valign="middle")
                buttonright = Button(text=f'{i} right', size_hint=(1, None), height=y * 0.1, halign="left", valign="middle")
                self.add_widget(buttonleft)
                self.add_widget(buttonright)
    
    
    class Wochentage(BoxLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Wochentage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            button = Button(size_hint=(.5, 1))
            button.text = "Zeit"
            button2 = Button(size_hint=(1, 1))
            button2.text = "Plan"
            self.add_widget(button)
            self.add_widget(button2)
    
    
    class Datum(BoxLayout):
        text_input_str = StringProperty("tag")
    
        def ooon_text_validate(self, widget):
            self.text_input_str = widget.text
            print(self.text_input_str)
            # self.ids.label_am_arsch.text = self.text_input_str
            self.ids.which_day.text = "harald"
    
    
    # 2.2 Textinput --------------         <------ in here is my question
    
    class Alledaten(BoxLayout):
    
        # text_input_str = StringProperty("Tag 1")
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Alledaten, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            input_ab_wann = TextInput(hint_text="Ab Tag: ",
                                      hint_text_color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
                                      background_color=(1, 1, 1, 1),
                                      halign="center",
                                      multiline=False)
                                      # ids="input_ab_wann_id")
    
            # input_ab_wann.bind(on_text_validate=Datum().ooon_text_validate)       <----- **whyyy does this not go inside the function ooon_text_validate?**
    
            def on_text(widget):
                Datum().ooon_text_validate(widget)  # <------ **but with this the terminal prints the input text, but doesn't change the Label text**
    
            input_ab_wann.bind(on_text_validate=on_text)
    
            self.add_widget(input_ab_wann)
    
    
    # 3. Appearance ----------------------------------
    class Spalteprotag(BoxLayout):
        pass
    
    
    # 4. Screens -------------------------------------
    class Maininterface(Screen):
        def float_in_int(self, float, **kwargs):
            super(Maininterface).__init__(**kwargs)
            de_int = float
            return int(de_int)
    
    
    # ----------------------------------
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Wochenplan().run()
```

'''

and my kv file:

'''

```
    <Screenmanager>:
        Maininterface:
    
    <Maininterface>:
        # 1. Stufe
        BoxLayout:
            # 1. vBox -> 2. hBox -> 3. vBox -> 4. Grid 2 cols
            orientation: "vertical"
            size: root.width, root.height
    
            # 1. Stufe
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: (1, .15)
                orientation: "horizontal"
    
                Alledaten:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    size_hint: (.3, 1)
    
                Label:
                    text: "Wochenplan"
                    size_hint: (1, 1)
                    # texture_size: self.size
                    text_size: self.size
                    halign: "center"
                    valign: "middle"
                    markup: True
                    font_size: dp(20)
                    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    
                Label:
                    text: ""
                    size_hint: (.3, .5)
    
            Datum:             # <------ in here is my Label
    
    # 2. Stufe
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        # 1 Spalte in Tabelle
        Spalteprotag:

        # 2 Spalte in Tabelle
        # Spalteprotag:
    
    
    <Spalteprotag>:
        # -> BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        # size_hint: (.25, 1)
    
        # 3. Stufe
    
        Wochentage:
            size_hint: (1, .1)
    
        ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    Zeitplanprotag:
        cols: 2
        height: self.minimum_height
        size_hint_y: None
        # row_default_height: 100
        row_force_default: False
        # spacint: 10
    
    <Zeitplanprotag>:
        # 4. Stufe -> GridLayout
    
    <Wochentage>:
    
    <Datum>:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1, .1)
    
        TextInput:
            id: zweite_input
            hint_text: "this text input is just an example to show my question\n ->> the textinput above should work like that one!"
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.text_input_str = self.text
    
        Label:           #      <------ this is the label which causes problems
            id: which_day
            # text: root.text_input_str
            text: root.text_input_str
            # background_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            # size_hint: (1, 1)
    
    <Alledaten>:
    
        # TextInput:
        #    id: ab_tag_textin
        #    hint_text:"Ab Tag: "
        #    hint_text_color:(0, 0, 0, 1)
        #    background_color:(1, 1, 1, 1)
        #    halign:"center"
        #    multiline:False
        #    on_text_validate: Datum.ooon_text_validate = self.text    <---- I tried it with an TextInput in the kv File but I did't know how to reference to another class...   
                                                                            if someone knows the solution via kv file im also very happy, but I want to now what I did wrong in my way to fix it via python file...
```

'''